# Proving function to be infinitely differentiable with help of induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am trying to prove that following function is infinitely differentiable with help of induction.

> $$e(x) = \begin{cases}
> \exp\left(-1/x\right),\quad&x>0,\\
> 0,&x\leq 0
> \end{cases}
> $$

$$\frac{e^1(x)}{e(x)} = \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Taking derivatives,

$$\therefore \frac{e(x)e^2(x) - (e^1(x))^2}{(e(x))^2} = \frac{-2}{x^3}$$

$$\therefore \frac{e^2(x)}{e(x)} = \left(\frac{e^1(x)}{e(x)}\right)^2 + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^1(x)}{e(x)}\right)$$

So, general formula :

$$ \frac{e^n(x)}{e(x)} = \left(\frac{e^{(n-1)}(x)}{e(x)}\right)^2 + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{(n-1)}(x)}{e(x)}\right)$$

I am not able to prove this for (n+1)th after assuming it for nth. It is becoming too complex. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Show by induction that for $x>0$ and for all $n\geq 0$,
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\exp\left(-1/x\right)\right)=\exp\left(-1/x\right)\cdot \frac{P_n(x)}{x^{2n}}$$
where $P_n(x)$ is some polynomial. You don't need the specific formula for $P_n$ because 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\exp\left(-1/x\right)\cdot \frac{Q(x)}{x^{2n}}=0$$
for any polynomial $Q$.

P.S. To prove that the derivative at $0$ exists, we use the following argument. If $f$ is continuous in $[0,\delta]$ and differentiable in $(0,\delta)$ then by the [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for $t\in (0,\delta)$, there is $s_t \in (0,t)$ such that
$$\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=f'(s_t).$$
Hence, if we know that $\lim_{s\to 0^+}f'(s)=L$ then $\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=L$, which means that the derivative of $f$ at $0$ exists and it is equal to $L$.

Comment: By this method we can get answer. But in details, if we prove recursive formula of $\frac{e^n(x)}{e(x)}$ by induction, then can we say that nth derivative exist?

Comment: Actually you verify that the $n$-th derivative at $0$ exists by showing that the limit of the $n$-th derivative for $x\to 0+$ exists (it is always 0 here). See P.S. in my edited answer.

Comment: Ok. So I should prove that $\lim_{x\to0} exist. If we put this limit on recursive formula, then limit on first term exist because (n-1)th derivative exists. Existence of limit of second term can be proved using MVT. Right?

Comment: @MeetR But in your recursive formula the limit as $x\to 0^+$of $\frac{|e^{(n)}(x)|}{e(x)}$ is $+\infty$!, Infact $\frac{e^{(n)}(x)}{e(x)}$ is the rational function $\frac{P_n(x)}{x^{2n}}$.

Comment: Ok. So this method won't work.

Comment: @MeetR You can use it in this way. The recursive formula shows by induction that $\frac{e^{(n)}(x)}{e(x)}$ is a rational function $R_n(x)$ (a square of a r,f is a r,f, the derivative of a r.f. is a r.f.). Then it is easy to see that $e^{(n)}=e(x)R_n(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x\to 0^+$.